# How to programmatically modify MultibodyPlant geometric parameters in pydrake?

Tags: python, drake

I'm currently loading in a URDF file of a robot, but want to be able to make modifications to geometric parameters of the `MultibodyPlant` object, such as changing the link lengths. What is the correct way to go about this in pydrake? I see methods like `AddJoint` that seem to indicate the ability to modify the robot but am unsure how to modify existing bodies within the `MultibodyPlant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultibodyPlant` parameters (with just a few remaining exceptions) are contained as parameters in the `Context`.  You can change them directly in the context, and therefore change the dynamics.

For a notebook that exercises this workflow, you might take a look at the `Multibody parameters in Drake` exercise I have here: http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/sysid.html#example3